# dvd writer taking 35 minutes to finish a 4.3GB DVD+-R disc. should it take only 10 minutes? should I replace the drive?

Tags: dvd, media, compact-disc

dvd writer taking 35 minutes to finish a 4.3GB DVD+-R disc. should it take only 10 minutes? should I replace the drive? its writing in 8x speed
 my computer is new dell vostro 200 cpu with 2gb ram and core 2 duo processor. there's 500gb of hard drive space.
  i use nero burning software. its taking 35 minutes to finish burning a dvd. any solution? should i replace the dvd rw?

Comment: You should go through some of your other questions and accept some of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it takes a long time, it depends how much data is being written.

To be honest, 35 minutes does seem like a long time, and you may want to upgrade to a faster drive - but personally I would do a check to make sure that the burnt disk is 100% correct, and if it is, I would leave it.

If you burn disks frequently, you may want to change for a faster drive. Mind you, I am not sure you can get faster in a laptop.

Comment: the machine is already fast with 2gb ram and core 2 duo intel processor. irrespective of the files it still takes 35 minutes. even if its 3 files of 1.4gb each (.mov files)

Comment: @user15660 - but what happens / how long does it take if you just want to burn a 1KB (or smaller) test file? 3 1.4gb files is huge and an average time for that can be over 20 minutes.

Comment: my friends computer can burn 4.3 GB of data (multiple files, small files etc) in less than 10 minutes in 8x speed. how come mine is not doing. i remember my machine doing the same many months/years ago. now i don't remember it correctly

Comment: @user15660 it can really be a number of things. The most common reason is poor media (your burner will automatically drop the speed if it detects a problem). Also though, as you said you used to be able to - it could simply be the age of the drive as they do deteriorate over time. (e.g. I support a (non-mastered) duplication facilitiy and they usually replace after around 1000 burns, depending on make).

Comment: I think my media is good because its 16X brand new memorex right out of the box. may be because of age. but the machine is only 1.5 years old. hmm... i will try with a different drive connected to it and see how long it takes. i don't see any other options. other feedbacks welcome. thanks